# Dagger not injecting my static instance properties in libGDX

Tags: java, dependency-injection, libgdx, dagger-2, dagger

I have the following application class for a libGDX game:

```java
@Module
public class MainGame extends Game {

    private AssetManager assetManager;

    // Instance
    private static MainGame instance;

    public static MainGame getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Provides
    public static AssetManager assetManager() {
        return instance.assetManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        // Set instance
        instance = this;

        // Tools
        assetManager = new AssetManager();
    }
}
```

The problem is that my `AssetManager` is not getting injected in my screens.

```java
public class LoadingScreen extends ScreenAdapter {

    private final String TAG = LoadingScreen.class.getSimpleName();

    @Inject AssetManager assetManager; // This is null

    @Override
    public void show() {
        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Entered screen");
        loadGraphics();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update(delta);
        Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(209 / 255f, 232 / 255f, 232 / 255f, 1);
        Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How are you getting an instance of `LoadingScreen`?  Also, what does your Dagger component look like?

Comment: I am creating that inside the `create` method using `loadingScreen = new LoadingScreen();`